# I was wondering how I could resolve this parse error

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could fix this ![parse]https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKQat.jpg error. My ![HTML]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST31r.jpg code linking to the css site is here. The link to the website I put to the href is here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Please include code as part of your question rather than linking to images. In this case you could just include an example of your css variable declarations and then an error message.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the following link the W3C CSS Validator doesn't support CSS variables yet which is why you are seeing parse errors. Your code is correct.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/css-custom-property-or-variable-gives-validation-error-but-why/234744